# what is the local when rc.local is run

Tags: locale

I have a java webapp which is auto started via rc.local which uses jasper to generate a pdf which has currency symbols.  The currency symbol used is '$' when I start the app from root manually it produces the desired '£' symbol.  What do I need to set to run the desired symbol via the rc.local please?

Comment: You can _force_ an application to use a specific locale, see (stackoverflow.com): [Forcing "date" to use a locale other than the machine default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896509/forcing-date-to-use-a-locale-other-than-the-machine-default), which is about `date` to a different locale, but using `LC_ALL` will change the entire locale settings.

Comment: Also note: "IMPORTANT: It is important to remember /etc/rc.local is discontinued and replaced. The current method to run scripts at boot is described after instructions to enable /etc/rc.local."  (https://linuxhint.com/use-etc-rc-local-boot/)